# Open info window in finder by applescript

Tags: applescript, finder

I've some problems to find the correct apple script command: I want to open the info window for a given file or folder. It's that window which I can open via cmd+i in Finder. Now I want to be able to automate this action by script file.
My code actually looks like this:

```
set aFile to POSIX file "/Users/xyz/Documents/test.rtf"
tell application "Finder" to open information window of aFile
```

But that doesn't work. The error message says that the file "information window of Macintosh HD:Users:xyz:Documents:test.rtf" cannot opened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some commands are picky with posix file. So we can coerce that to something else and it will work...

```
set aFile to (POSIX file "/Users/xyz/Documents/test.rtf") as alias
tell application "Finder" to open information window of aFile
```

or

```
set aFile to (POSIX file "/Users/xyz/Documents/test.rtf") as text
tell application "Finder" to open information window of file aFile
```